# deploying the smart contract with hardware wallet

Tags: anchor, solana-program, deploy, ledger-nano

would u plz help me with how can I deploy the smart contract written with anchor with a hardware wallet (ledger nano)? Hardware wallet doesn't have any keypair and I am not sure what should be as the wallet address in anchor.toml, e.g. here:

[provider]
cluster = "mainnet"
wallet = "/Users/MyAccount/my-Solana-wallet/mySol-keypair.json"

Tnx

Answer (score 1):

on the CLI you reference a ledger with `usb://ledger`

Answer (score 1):

tnx for answer.means it is enough if I set my solana address and anchor.toml wallet address to usb://ledger and then run solana program deploy?